# pros and cons of NSLocalizedString without comment

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

What are the advantages and disadvantages of creating following function in a project:

```
@warn_unused_result
public func NSLocalizedString(key: String) -> String {
    return NSLocalizedString(key)
}
```

Mostly, we fill `NSLocalizedString` like this: `NSLocalizedString("somekey", comment: "")`. Therefore, the code would be more readable, but are there any tools that could be not used, or any other problems we are not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command line utility called genstrings that goes through all the source code in your project, finds calls to NSLocalizedString, and builds a Localized.strings file from what it finds.

I haven't tried to use it on Swift files yet, so I'm not sure if it even works, but your function might cause problems with that.

Comment: Yes, but `genstrings` does not know how to update existing Localizable.string files, so we won't be using it

Comment: there is an [update script](https://github.com/anlcan/AcbUpdateStrings) but it still has some flaws (I already tried it some time ago)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a 3rd party localization service the comment can provide context for the translator. Keep in mind that the service many not have access to the computer code.

Comment: yes, but it is not being filled anyways, I mean, if we were to use such a tool later, we could still extend the functions with the comment